# Как найти контакты профиля stackoverflow?

Tags: поддержка, stackoverflow

Как найти контакты профиля stackoverflow, уже час копаю, ничего найти не могу.

Comment: Какие контакты, какого профиля?

Comment: Нет тут никаких контактов, если сам участник себе в био их не добавил.

Comment: А как написать участнику?

Comment: @Pavel Стандартного функционала для связи с участником нет. Можно посмотреть его профиль, возможно, там будут контакты. Также можно попробовать создать чат-комнату и пригласить его в неё (с определённого уровня репутации).

Comment: Спасибо большое!